# Cómo puedo hacer esta función utilizando open basic de excel?

Tags: excel, visual, basic

Necesito hacer una función que dado un número de 3 cifras retorne el número invertido.

Ejemplos: al llamado invertir(791) retornará 197
al llamado invertir(248) retornará 842.

Necesito algo parecido a la estructura y palabras reservadas de este código:

```
Function f_perimetro(ByVal r As Integer)
Dim Perimetro As Double
Perimetro = 2 * 3.1416 * r
f_perimetro = Perimetro
```

End Function

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te recomiendo leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas mejorar tus preguntas. Agrega un ejemplo mínimo replicable de lo que deseas o tienes problema, para poder partir de ahí.

Comment: ese codigo no tiene nada pero nada que ver ocn lo que pedis...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera sencilla:

```
  Function Capicua (valor as String)
  Capicua = Int (StrReverse(valor))
  End Function
```

A la función le he llamado Capicua y contiene un parámetro llamado valor, definido como cadena de texto String.
Luego se invierte mediante StrReverse y se convierte nuevamente a un número mediante Int.
Desde las celdas de excel puedes llamar a esta función escribiendo Capicua y seleccionado la celda sobre la cual aplicarás la inversión.